# Fitting Poisson Distribution to data and calculating probabilities

Tags: probability, statistics

> Michael, the produce manager at the local Albertson's supermarket store, would like you to estimate the probability that a customer will purchase 5 or more bunches of bananas.  He has collected the following data:
>
> $$
> \begin{array}{c|c}
> \text{N=Number of bunches of bananas} & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & \text{5 or more}\\
> \hline
> \text{Frequency} & 49 & 35 & 12 & 3 & 1 & 0\\
> \\
> \\
> \end{array}
> $$
>
> (a) Calculate the mean and the variance for the aforementioned data.
>
> (b)  Which distribution (Poisson, binomial, or negative binomial) would you use to model the data?  Which parameter(s) would you choose?
>
> (c)  If 1000 customers visit the store, estimate the probability that someone will purchase 5 or more bunches of bananas.

To start, I first calculate the mean and variance:

(a)  $E[N] = \frac{1}{100} (1 * 35 + \cdots+4*1) = 0.72$

$Var[N]=E[N^2]-E[N] = 1.26-0.72^2=0.7416$

(b)  Since $E[N] \approx Var[N]$, this can be modeled as a Poisson distribution because  in this distrubtion $E[N]=Var[N]=\lambda$, and here we can assign $\lambda=0.72$.

$ \therefore \Pr(N=k)= \cfrac{\lambda^k}{k!} e^{-\lambda} \text{ for } k \ge 0$

(c)  This part I'm a little confused.  The probability of purchasing 5 or more bananas can be written as

$\Pr[N \ge 5] = \sum\limits_{k=5}^{\infty} \cfrac{\lambda^k}{k!} e^{-\lambda}
= 1-\Pr[N<5] 
= 1-\sum\limits_{k=0}^{4} \cfrac{\lambda^k}{k!} e^{-\lambda}
=1 - 0.999110
=0.000889$

So is it correct to say if there is 1 person, the probability that he will choose 5 or more bunches of bananas is 0.00089??  Hence, if we have 1000 people the probability they will choose 5 or more is 0.00089^1000.  But this is wrong.  Can someone please explain?  How do I apply this probability to 1000 people?  This is where I am stuck.  Thanks in advance.

Oh by the way, does anyone know how to fix my tex code for the horizontal table?  I totally winged it and don't know the proper way.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability that a randomly chosen person will buy $5$ or more bunches is say $p$, where $p$ has been estimated to be $0.000889$ (I have not checked the calculation that led to this number: the basic method was right).

Thus  the probability she will **not** buy $5$ or more is $1-p$. The probability that $1000$ people in a row will not buy $5$ or more is $(1-p)^{1000}$. So the probability at least one person will buy $5$ or more is $1-(1-p)^{1000}$.

**Remark:** The Poisson model is a *model*. On the assumption that we do indeed have independent Poissons with parameter $0.72$,  the calculation is fully correct. However, it is possible that the store is in a village, so independence cannot be assumed.

Comment: Thanks @AndréNicolas, can you please explain what $p^{1000}$ means?  If $p$ is the probability that a person buys 5 or more bunches of bananas, then I thought $p^{1000}$ means the probability that 1000 people buy 5 or more bunches of bananas. Still a little confused can you please clarify?  What is the difference between $p^{1000}$ and $1-(1-p)^{1000}$?

Comment: Are you asking about what is the difference between $p^{1000}$ and $1-(1-p)^{1000}$? The first is incredibly tiny. The second is about $0.59$. The proability that a  person  buys $5$ or more is $p$. The probability she doesn't is $1-p$, about $0.99911$. The probability that $k$ people in a row are non-buyers is $(0.99911)^k$. For  $k=1000$ the calculator gives about $0.41$. So the probability at least one of the $1000$ is a buyer is about $1-0.41$.

Comment: $p^{1000}$ is the probability that all 1000 people buy 5 or more bananas, i.e. P(person 1 buys 5 or more AND person 2 buys 5 or more AND ...). The question asks for the probability that *at least* one person buys 5 or more, i.e. P(person 1 buys 5 or more OR person 2 buys 5 or more OR ...). We can say that P(at least one person buys 5 or more) is the complement of P(no-one buys 5 or more), i.e. P(at least one) + P(no-one) = 1.

Comment: So P(no-one buys 5 or more) = P(person 1 *doesn't* buy 5 or more AND person 2 *doesn't* buy 5 or more AND ...) = P(person 1 doesn't) * P(person 2 doesn't) * ..., and we can say that the probability that a particular person doesn't buy 5 or more bananas is given by $1-p$, i.e. it's the complement of the probability that they do. So P(no-one buys 5 or more bananas) = $(1-p)*(1-p)*(1-p)*...=(1-p)^{1000}$.

Comment: Thanks both of you.  That's the filler I was looking for.